# Is there a way to bring back new experimental Stack Overflow design?

Tags: discussion, april-fools, time-machine

On April 1st there was introduced a new design on this site. And now it suddenly has been rolled back. Is there a way to bring it back? Maybe with some additional browser extensions or whatever. I really miss it.

[image]

Comment: Found the answer here:
https://stackapps.com/questions/8287/2019-april-fools-day-retro-theme
Direct link to the theme:
https://github.com/a-stone-arachnid/Time-Travel-Mode